# Powershell Script To Display Stopped Processes With an input Parameter to filter

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to Powershell, but for the life of me I can't find how to do this anywhere on Google.

Here's what I need my script to look like when executing.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvnLS.jpg

While I have managed to get my script to display the stopped processes. I haven't been able to get it to filter by parameter. ( I also have the parameter working as well)

Here's my Code.

```
param ([string]$myVariable)
"DATE AND TIME IS"
"$((Get-Date).toString())"
"The following $myVariable Services are currently stopped on: $(HostName)"
Get-Service | Where-Object {($_.status -eq "stopped")
"List of stopped services complete."
"Script Terminating"
powershell -noexit
```

So far I've got it to display the stopped services. I've tried entering another parameter on the same line wit the get service, to force it to further filter the output. But Every time I do that, it always throws an error.

I've tried:
filtering by string
filtering by firstletter of (myVariable)

And I can't find anything else to try on Google. Everyone keeps recommending what I've already tried =
Any help would be greatly appreciated!! :)

Comment: I'm sorry. the Variable is passed into the script when executing FROM powershell it appears.

So basically the script is executed by calling its line, and passing in a variable after that.

Example beiing:   File/System/Path/Script.ps1 A

From there it will search for All "A" Related fields

Comment: gotcha, one second i'll provide an answer

Comment: Actually I think i got it....

in the Get-Service Line. Change it too

      Get-Service $myVariable* | Where-Object {($_.status eq "stopped")}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to change this one line.

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {($_.status -eq "stopped" -and $_.Name.Substring(0,1) -eq $myVariable)}
```

So it filters down the services to the ones that are stopped and then beginning with the letter passed from the paramater? I think that's what your asking for?

Comment: Looks Good! Thanks!

Yeah that makes sense. It works...  However whats the point of the substring? So it only finds applications with the description/displayname?

Comment: All we’re doing here is taking our service name string variable and calling the Substring method. This allows us to compare the first letter of the name with our variable. All the services have a name so it will find all of the services stopped AND beginning with the letter passed. However, if you are passing more than just a letter as a parameter, you will have to compare more of the substring letters. Hope this helps. Please add a comment if down voting.

Answer (score 1):

In the get-service line

Use

```
 get-service $myVariable* | where-object {($_.status -eq "stopped")}
```